# How can I preserve an active redstone circuit when I leave the chunk it's built in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

When I set up a redstone circuit for rotating blocks (with pistons) or flashing redstone lights, everything's fine, but when I exit that zone, the current is not saved, and when I return later, the blocks have stopped moving or the lights have stopped flashing.

I don't want to reassemble part of the circuit each time I come by -- How can I keep the redstone circuit running when I'm far away?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Redstone state is not saved when a chunk unloads, however entity state *is*. This means minecarts will continue to move when a chunk is reloaded. This in turn means if you replace your redstone clock generators with minecart based clock generators, they'll resume ticking when a chunk is reloaded. Here's the most basic Minecart ticker:

[image: Minecart ticker]

You can adjust the lengths of track to get the length of tick you require, and you can combine with other tickers outputs `AND`ed together to fine tune the length of the tick.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to mess around with minecart timings, you can use one of these to "jump start" a pure-redstone circuit.

Comment: @Ben yup, that too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: Redstone Repeaters will not update properly across a reload. However, Redstone Torches will, so if you build your system's clocks with torches then they will continue working.