# How do you make the most compact rapid redstone pulser that never stops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do you make the most compact rapid redstone pulser that never stops?

And in my friend's server, the rapid redstone pulser stops after some time, and I have no idea why, how do you prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 designs in mind:

[image: Design 1]

and also this

[image: design 2]

The third design is slowest but it is also the smallest,

[image: design 3]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with any always-on redstone design (including pulsars) is that they will die or glitch when no players are close enough to keep the chunk in memory.  Redstone current is not saved with the world.

There are a couple of ways to combat this, both of which have been covered in previous questions here.  You can either [add a "jump-start" component](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28462/how-can-i-preserve-an-active-redstone-circuit-when-i-leave-the-chunk-its-built-i) to the circuit to get it started again after re-load or use a Bukkit mod to [keep some chunks loaded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28762/keep-some-chunks-loaded-in-minecraft-smp) regardless of player distance.

Comment: But what if I am just experimenting with redstone and not intending to keep it

Comment: Then I'd recommend going with the minecart jump start described in the first question I linked.  It's non-permanent and easy to tear down (to move or recycle), so it's great for just playing around.  And having it means you don't have to worry about your experiments breaking if you get too far away from them.

Comment: This is not true. Some redstone contraptions can load themselves.  https://youtu.be/XcYuDsKiHxs is an example of a machine that pulses so fast that it cannot be unloaded

Comment: Now do note that the first version as displayed in the linked video is unable to handle some things, but there are updated versions by xcom6000 that function as a full permaloader even without the permaloader setup.

Answer (score 1):

I know another way to make it far more compact see picture. If you power input it turns the pulser off (de-powering the input will make the pulser resume). to start it power and then de-power the piston. ta da! most compact pulser I have ever seen.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use a comparator and a redstone block it is smaller than ProSay's and goes fast
use the comparator with the light in the front turned on and put the redstone
block as the input then put redstone as the output and the input b

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very unclear. Do you think you could post a screenshot or something to clarify it?

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Use a sticky piston, a redstone block and two redstone dust. Attach the piston pointing parallel to the ground, attach the redstone block to it, and put the redstone dust next to both piston and block. Ta-da!